# How to display django tags in update form (django-taggit)?

Tags: django, django-taggit

I made a basic blog post app in django and I'm using the django-taggit project (https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit) to create taggable Model objects. However, tags show up as a query set in my update form field:

`<QuerySet[<Tag:wow]>`

Here is what my html looks like:

`<input type="text" name="tags" data-role="tagsinput" class="form-control" id="tags" name="tags" value="{{ post.tags.all }}">`

I know there's a way to loop through the tags when displaying them, but is there a way to loop through them within the form? I'm using a single text field to add tags separated by a comma using this tutorial:

https://dev.to/coderasha/how-to-add-tags-to-your-models-in-django-django-packages-series-1-3704

I don't have an issue saving tags. My only issue is displaying tags that already exist in an editable field on my update form.

thanks!

forms.py:

```
from taggit.forms import TagWidget

    class PostForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            widgets = {'content_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 80}),
                        'tags': TagWidget(),
                    } 
            fields = ['title', 'video_URL', 'content_text', 'score', 'tags',]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`post.tags.all` is a queryset so it does not get evaluated since django queries are *lazy* and you just get the queryset since this returns a *set of data (array if you want)* not an value. Try this:

```py
<input type="text" name="tags" data-role="tagsinput" class="form-control" id="tags" name="tags" value="{% for tag in post.tags.all %}{{ tag }},{% endfor %}">
# I used a comma to separate them but feel free to use whatever you want
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! I didn't know you could do that within a html value attribute.